# In Javascript, how do I put single quotes around an array I just "joined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
[3, 4, 5]
['4', '1', 'abc123']


function combine_ids(ids){
    return ids.join(',');
};
```

No matter what type of list, I want my function to return a string with **single quotes** around the elements.

The function should return:

```
'3','4','5'
```

and

```
'4','1','abc123'
```

I want my resulting string to have single quotes in them!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple logic!

```js
function combine_ids(ids) {
  return (ids.length ? "'" + ids.join("','") + "'" : "");
}
console.log(combine_ids([]));
console.log(combine_ids([3]));
console.log(combine_ids([3, 4, 'a']));
```

Example output:

> ```
> (an empty string)
> '3'
> '3','4','a'
> ```

Comment: isn't this putting single quotes around the entire list instead of around each element as requested?

Comment: @Triptych: I think the example and live demonstration should satisfy your doubts, as well as the simple code! Pay special attention to the argument passed to `ids.join`.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I put single quotes around an array I just “joined”?

Your approach seems to be unnecessarily complex. You better off:

1. Create intermediate array with all elements converted `toString` and quoted
2. `join` the intermediate array

---

```
[03:22:35.728] [3, 4, 5].map( function (element) { return "'" + String(element) + "'" } ).join(",")
[03:22:35.736] "'3','4','5'"
--
[03:22:58.925] ['4', '1', 'abc123'].map( function (element) { return "'" + String(element) + "'" } ).join(",")
[03:22:58.933] "'4','1','abc123'"
```

Note: `map` method required JS 1.6+, versions below are requiring you to iterate an array "manually":

```
function combine_ids( array ) {
  var tmp = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    tmp[i] = "'" + String( array[i] ) + "'";
  }
  return tmp.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
 function myjoin(arr) {
   return "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
 }
```